# Microsoft visual studio "value was either too large or too small for int32" while trying to train a neural network with tensorflow 2.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am following a tutorial for tensorflow and I ran into an issue because when I try to execute this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  LOAD AND SPLIT DATASET
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

class_names = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer',
               'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=4, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images,  test_labels, verbose=2)
print(test_acc)
```

on VS2022 it spits out the "value is either too large or too small for int32".
But when I try the same code on google colab it just works fine.

P.S. I have also tried with tensorflow 2.7 but it gives the same error.

Complete cmd prompt output:

```
2022-01-23 10:50:06.677292: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-01-23 10:50:07.109899: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5961 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
Epoch 1/4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

And when I press a key to continue there is a popup:
[image]

Going line per line in debug mode I found that this is the line that fails (it does so the second time it is called):
[image]

Comment: Did you try making sure to use a 64-bit build? (I assume you have a reasonably new computer which supports this?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do you mean a 64-bit build of VS? Because I am already using a python 3.9 (64-bit) environment.

Comment: I assume that implies a 64-bit build of Tensorflow as well, but I don't use any of this stuff myself. Just the first thing that comes to mind. A [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message would probably help.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated the question with all the output info that I have; if there is anything more that I can append please do let me know.

Comment: You may try running again this code in latest version of `Tensorflow 2.7`. You can upgrade existing `TensorFlow` to the latest version using `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.

Comment: @TFer2 Even with everything updated it still spits out the same output with the same error